# How to sort nested properties in the field column definition of ag-grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

```
var data = [{
   id: {
        id: "108662", 
        absoluteUri:"abc.com", 
        devicedisplayId: "045551"
       }
  devicename: "Printer"
}]

var columnDefs = [

     {
      headerName: 'Device Id', field: 'id',filter:
      'agTextColumnFilter',sortable: true,
      filterValueGetter : function(params) {
         return params.data.id.devicedisplayId;
      },
     cellRenderer: function(params) {
        return '<a href=" ' + params.value.absoluteUri + '" target="_blank">' + 
                 params.value.devicedisplayId+ '</a>';
      }
   }
```

I have nested data.wanted to achieve sorting based on devicedisplayId. i have used filterValueGetter to filter but did not came across any such function w.r.to sorting.

Comment: Hi, the sort function doesn't use `filterValueGetter` but `valueGetter`.

Comment: Hi i have tried with valueGetter but it seems to be not sorting.

Comment: Ok, can you create [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-vbv6yy) repro? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For custom sorting function you can use the ***comparator*** method in column definition like so.

```
    comparator: (id1, id2) => {
    if (id1.devicedisplayId < id2.devicedisplayId) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (id1.devicedisplayId < id2.devicedisplayId) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Check **Custom Sorting** in ag-grid documentation for more details - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-sorting/#custom-sorting